# JavaScript - dynamically start/stop function with an unlimited loop

Tags: javascript

What are best practices about dynamic starting/stopping functions with an unlimited loop inside or long running?

Imagine that user wants to enable showing FPS on the screen of application. To do that - javascript should do the calculations on every frame, limitless. But then user wants to turn off this - function must stop completely, without any continuous CPU load.

Can you show any good example how to do that? I believe checking "if (stop) => return" on every iteration is something not ideal.

Comment: use `setInterval` and `clearInterval`

Comment: Also, you should know by now that you don't get code written here, you get help with written code.

Comment: You can do this with [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame). Although the CPU load of immediately exiting a function again is negligible.

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, with a **setInterval** there is a similar approach to the given example?

Comment: Due to there being so many ways of doing this and answers being influenced by opinion, this question is almost certainly too broad and/or opinion based and should be closed.  That being said: [Web Worker](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option is to use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) which returns a number to reference the interval so we can clear it when we call [clearInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearInterval).

In this example we will call render 100 times and then clear the interval:

```js
let count = 1
let interval = null

function render() {
  console.clear()

  // Lets make some fake bs numbers just for example
  console.log("FPS: " + Math.floor(Math.random() * 30))
  count++
  
  // After 100 calls lets clear the interval
  if(count > 100) clearInterval(interval)
}

// Replace 100 with a smaller number to run faster 
// or use a higher number to run the interval slower
interval = setInterval(render, 100)
```

Comment: This feels more efficient to me, thanks! As in general you don't need to calculate the FPS on every frame, it could be enough once per second, for example, and there is no flag checking. Maybe you know - does the JavaScript internally checks the value of **interval** on every iteration? ..to know should it continue or not. Or it's done by JS compiler/runtime. Maybe wrong words of the question, but I hope you understood the idea

Comment: interval is what is returned all you need it for is to pass it to `clearInterval` so it know which interval you want to stop so if you have 10 different `setIntervals` passing the result of one of the `setInterval` to `clearInterval`, JavaScript will know which one to stop. If you do a `console.log(interval)` you will see that it is a number

Answer (score 2):

> What are best practices about dynamic starting/stopping functions with an unlimited loop inside or long running?

There shouldn't be an infinite loop at all. It blocks the whole thread and freezes the page. Javascripts power is to manage asynchronous events and tasks, and thats what you should do here: a very fast interval that executes a certain task very often, but not the whole time. Now to stop that you could simply use a flag.

> Can you show any good example how to do that?

As you were talking about FPS, you could make a rendering "loop", measure its frames per second and disable that somewhen:

```
 let measure = true; // the flag
 const start = Date.now();
 let count = 1;

 (function render() {
    // Draw something onto the screen
    // measure
    if(measure)
      console.log("FPS: " + (count++ * 1000 / (Date.now() - start)));
    requestAnimationFrame(render); // the async rendering task handler
 })();
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/dogicawori/edit?output)

Now you can set `measure` to false somewhen and it will stop logging.

> I believe checking "if (stop) => return" on every iteration is something not ideal.

If you worry about that nanosecond you should consider writing your code in assembly.

Comment: Thanks for example! And if you want to start/stop/start/stop ... so on ... running this function - how would you do that? In you example it runs only once

Comment: @alexey no it does not run only once, try it :)

Comment: oh, right, it continues to run on every frame. But is there a way to stop the function (and loop) completely?

Comment: Yes there is. Just use another flag?

Comment: You mean to "return" when needed? And then to re-launch the function - call it as a standard function again?

Comment: to stop it, don't call `requestAnimationFrame` and it wont run again

Comment: @GetOffMyLawn, so we could just put "request..." inside a "if" check?! :)

Comment: yeah. here is a one liner: `shouldRequest && requestAnimationFrame(render)` where `shouldRequest` is a `true/false` value